# load data using SqlLoader don't use auto extending TableSpace

Tags: unix, oracle11g, sql-loader

I try to load data in table X via data file using sqlLoader , but I get this error :

**ORA-01688: unable to extend table X partition SYS_X by 16 in tableSpace TS_X .**

I understand that the tableSpace  has 0 free space but the option of auto extending this tableSpace was ON ,and despite that it doesn't extend automatically.

what's the problem exactly ,did i miss something (options in sqlLoader )?

Comment: Please check the max limit of data file assigned to tablespace, there is possibility that data file has reached to its limit.

Comment: Check if you have free diskspace where datafiles are located